# c# MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue, parameters to express a table, resulted command have a single quote added

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, parameters

my problem is that two undesired single quote appear in my command when i use AddWithValue.
This is how i call my function:

```
string sqlTableName = "the_table_i_want";
DataTable myDataTable = SQLcom.SelectLastValueInTab(sqlTableName);
```

My Function;

```
public static DataTable SelectLastValueInTab(string TableName)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @TabName ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", con))
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TabName", TableName);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader testreader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The Resulted command is :

```
"SELECT * FROM 'the_table_i_want' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

And is suppose to be :

```
"SELECT * FROM the_table_i_want ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

It cause the program to crash beacause i have:

```
a syntax error near ''the_table_i_want' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'
```

PS : if i don't use AddWithValuechange and change

```
@TabName for the_table_i_want
```

in the MySqlCommand it works perfectly !

Thanks a lot !

Daniel G.B

Comment: You cannot use parameters to express a table or field name. You can use them only for the values.

Comment: Prepared statements weren't exactly meant to be used this way. The `AddWithValue` method sees that it is a string and quotes it for you. If `TableName` is not user supplied, just concatenate it in with your query, but surround it with square brackets: `"SELECT * FROM [" + TableName + "] ..."` or whichever system your RDBMS uses (backticks?). You way also want to have a valid list of table names listed somewhere. If `TableName` is not in that list, don't execute the query. This should protect you enough from SQL injection.

Comment: @Steve thanks a lot that was exactly my problem ! But there is no specification of this in the [method definition ?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Pay the utmost attention with the accepted answer. You know the problem with Sql Injection so don't let the user type the tables. At least let him/her choose the names from a predefined combo or list with just the correct values.

Comment: @Steve thanks steve but dont worry this function parameter is not a user entry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, You cannot use parameters to express a table or field name. Alternative approach would be appending the table name to the query.

```
public static DataTable SelectLastValueInTab(string TableName)
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        string qry = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(qry, con))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader testreader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .Work perfectly.